# How to customize the google custom search bar API with own css

Tags: javascript, html, css

This might be pretty simple though, but I can't figure out how to customize Google custom search bar API with my site css. I have tried applying several predefined css classes with restrained `div` width but its seems the search bar its still out of style with and `iframe` look.

This is my code: how do I apply a css to it

```
<html>
    <head>
        <div width="100%" id="cse" style="width: 100%;">Loading</div>
        <script src="http://www.google.com/jsapi" type="text/javascript">
        </script>
        <script type="text/javascript"> 
            google.load('search', '1', {language: 'en', style: google.loader.themes.V2_DEFAULT});
            google.setOnLoadCallback(function() {
                var customSearchOptions = {};
                var customSearchControl = new google.search.CustomSearchControl('009437919812836441502:rka9ujkwvwe', customSearchOptions);
                customSearchControl.setResultSetSize(google.search.Search.FILTERED_CSE_RESULTSET); 
                customSearchControl.draw('cse');
            }, true);
        </script>
    </head>
</html>
```

Or is it possible at all?

Comment: I believe it's not possible. I tried it once and then it wasn't possible, but maybe things have changed since then.

Answer (score 1):

It seems possible, if you give me more example code aka the css you tried I can see where it isn't working for you.  Here is something I did to constrain the width of the search bar.

```
#cse .gsc-search-box {
   width: 200px;  
}​
```

JSFiddle: [Example Code](http://jsfiddle.net/5ZGwx/)

I am assuming that your CSS styles don't have a high enough specificity then those of the Google code so that is why you are not seeing your applied styles.  Your CSS styles need to have a larger CSS specificity then Google's in order for your styles to work. (Reference: [CSS Specificity: Things you should know](http://coding.smashingmagazine.com/2007/07/27/css-specificity-things-you-should-know/))

Let me know if that helps you move forward.

Comment: the css specifity site helped. Thanks, although i still got some flaws in my code

Comment: If this helped you with you question, give me credit :)  otherwise post your additional questions so I can help!

Answer (score 0):

My first suggestion is to not put any non-body HTML in the `<head>`. That is, move the `<div>` you have from the head to a `<body>` tag.

Second, you can definitely style Google's custom search box. You'll need to use something that lets you inspect the DOM, such as Web Developer Tools in Chrome or Firebug in Firefox (although, Firefox's built-in tools are decent now, too). Google uses that div to hook into your site and deliver more DOM elements via JavaScript. After the search box loads, you can inspect it using the developer tools and see all of the other elements it injects.

The main element you'll use to style are all related to the `.gsc-input` class. <strike>There's a Google document in support that talks about styling these things. I'll try to find and edit this post with the link later.</strike>  Here's a [Google example](https://developers.google.com/custom-search/docs/api?hl=en#searchbox) of styling the custom search box and results.

Comment: Thanks all for your contribution, but i think i will try using the css specificity stuff to constrain the cse search bar width. And